What is the definition of dependency in UML
In UML, we know there is a term "dependency".

We are eager to know what the definition of dependency is. For example:
class B {}

class A {
  constructor(b: B){...}
}


We know that the instantiation of b is not inside A. In this case, does it mean that A does not depend on B?
Person.ts imports Animal.ts. Then is Person.ts dependent on Animal.ts?

===
There is an relation answer, but I don't think it's a good explanation.

Dependency is the most general relationship between two elements.
You can think of the dependency relationship like this: A depends on B is changes to B might necessitate changes to A.
When talking about TypeScript, the first thing that indicates a dependency is the import keyword (note that sometimes there is an implicit import).

Looking at your cases:

A depends on B because changes in B might necessitate changes to A.
Person.ts depends on Animal.ts because changes in Animal.ts might necessitate changes to Person.ts.


P.S. For example, if there are association, aggregation, composition, generalization, or realization relationship between A and B, then A depends on B because changes to B might necessitate changes to A.

I would add to this answer, that once other relationship exists (e.g. association), there is no point in showing the dependency explicitly.

Thank you @Ister, I tried to supplement the answer.

From the UML v2.5.1 specifications

§7.7.1 Summary A Dependency signifies a supplier/client relationship
between model elements where the modification of a supplier may impact
the client model elements.
§7.7.3.1 Dependency A Dependency implies that the semantics of the
clients are not complete without the suppliers. The presence of Dependency relationships in a model does not have any runtime semantic
implications. The semantics are all given in terms of the
NamedElements that participate in the relationship, not in terms of
their instances.

So for you example, A depends on B. If B somehow changes (or gets deleted) A is impacted.
The same for your Person.ts and Animal.ts. If Animal.ts would be deleted then Person.ts would definitely be impacted.

Wouldn't it be better to write "If B is deleted then A is impacted." instead of "If B somehow changes (or gets deleted) A is impacted."  A change in the supplier might not impact the client, but deletion of the supplier must impact the client (otherwise there is no dependency).
